# Знаки препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Какими знаками препинания выделяются "я же говорю"/"я же говорил"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение ***я же говорил/говорю***  обычно оформляется в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения (БСП) и имеет изъяснительное значение (я же говорил, что...).

Соответственно, возможны три варианта знаков: **тире, двоеточие, запятая.**

1) **Часто используется тире.** В этом случае пауза обозначена, но он не такая длительная, как при двоеточии.

*Куда едете-то? ― Я же говорил ― к югу. Я же говорил ― он его найдет.*

2) **Двоеточие** ставится при подчеркнутой остановке голоса, в этом случае содержание второй части выделено в большей степени.

*Я же говорил: станут как шёлковые.*

3) **Запятая** ставится в том случае, если предложение имеет значение вводного замечания (пауза практически отсутствует, предложение выделено только ударением).

*Я же говорил, исправлю. Как ты тут оказался? ― Меня прислали, я же говорил.  Я же говорил, что-то нечисто!*